# nginx fastcgi rewrite: primary script unknown

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I have following nginx configuration:

```
  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ index.html =404;

      if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 last;
      }
  }


 location ~ .php$ {
    # protection from known vulnerability
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
 }
```

(`fastcgi_params` are defaults from Debian package)

it works for request `/`, however when the request is rewritten the main file is not found:

request is `/contact` which should be rewritten to `/index.php?url=contact`

```
 *104 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /contact HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost:8080"
```

I'm unable to get from logs what is actuall fastcgi trying to load, which path?

Comment: Please post the entire `server` block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `index.php` and `/index.php` are different URIs. You've forgotten slashes in your rewrites.

Answer (score 2):

This is a better way to implement the same functionality:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
}
```

and then your PHP location block as in your setup.

`try_files` checks first if the file matching $uri exists, then a directory, and if neither exists, it uses the rewrite -location, which runs the script.

Most likely reason your setup was not working was the missing `/` from the rewrite script path. Anyway, this setup is simpler is the preferred one with nginx.

Comment: why not `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri;` ?

Comment: Very good point, I have never even thought like that. Short and beautiful!